# How to set ipc with angular 9 service and electron main process

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I am facing issues with electron-angular (totally angular beginner here) ipc events. Here is my code:

Electronhelper.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ElectronhelperService {
  appSettings: any;
  constructor(private electron: ElectronService){
    this.fetchAllSettings() ;
  }

  fetchAllSettings(){
    this.electron.ipcRenderer.send('fetch:Settings') ;

    this.electron.ipcRenderer.once('fetch:Settings::recieved', (event, data) => {
      this.appSettings = data[0];
    });
  }
}
```

main.js(electron process, everything working fine here)

```js
ipcMain.on('fetch:Settings', () => {
   console.log('got on method')
   win.webContents.send('fetch:Settings::recieved', [settings])
}) ;
```

Now if use above service in another component or other service as a dependency in their respective constructors, then when i want to access `this.appSetting` in electronhelper.service.ts it always remains undefined. For example:

appconfig.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Settings } from '../interface/settings' ;
import { ElectronhelperService } from './electronhelper.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppconfigService {
  settings: Settings ;
  constructor(private helper: ElectronhelperService){
    console.log(this.helper.appSettings) ; // this returned as undefined
  }
}
```

I know that ipc events are async but how can I handle them inside these services. Also app settings are fetched from electron-store npm package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the settings synchronously, often an option if loading (and blocking) doesn't take too long:

```
fetchAllSettings() {
    this.appSettings = this.electron.ipcRenderer.sendSync('fetch:Settings')[0] ;
}
```

On the backend, you then don't use `event.reply` but assign the result to `event.returnValue`:

```
ipcMain.on('fetch:Settings', (event) => {
    const data = getTheSettings();
    event.returnValue = data;
}
```

Comment: if fetching setting or any other data takes some time and I wanted to show a loading icon until the settings had fully loaded how can i achieve that ?

Comment: I'd know how to do it with react or svelte but for angular, I hope some expert finds this and answers.